# CSS: Alternative min()

Tags: css

According to the size of the div, I want to set the `background-position-x` and the `background-size`.
Using only CSS without JS or JQuery, I use [min()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/min) which works:

```
.test {
  transition: all 0.5s;
  background-image: url(./my-asset.svg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: min(-50px, -100%);
  background-position-y: center;
  background-size: min(50px, 100%) 100%;
}
```

This works properly but only on recent browsers, but I have a Firefox target to v.68 and it is not compatible. 
What could be the alternative without using JS or JQuery and only CSS ?

I reproduce what I would like to have in output using min(). Hover the red part to make it work:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.use-px {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.use-percentage {
  margin-left: 200px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 3px black;
}

.left-over-image {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: all 1s;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: min(-50px, -100%);
  background-position-y: center;
  background-size: min(50px, 100%) 100%;
}

.left-over-image:hover {
  background-position: left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="use-px">
      <!-- It will use 50px, because 25% of 300px is 75px. -->
      <div class="left-over-image"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="use-percentage">
      <!-- It will use 100%, because 25% of 100px is 25px. -->
      <div class="left-over-image"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you sure about this new code? negative value inside min() ?

Comment: can you share a working example so we can see what you see. This code will show no background when the div is big

Comment: I did a working example @TemaniAfif

Comment: I see no image ...

Comment: I've changed the code to make it clearer. You see an image now? @TemaniAfif

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can consider a trick using pseudo element.

Resize both examples to see that they behave the same:

```css
.box {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue) 0/50px 50px no-repeat;
  background-position-x: min(4em, 100%);
}

.alt {
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  resize:both;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.alt::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  background:inherit;
  background:linear-gradient(red,blue) 0/50px 50px no-repeat;
  background-position-x:100%;
  max-width:calc(4em + 50px); /* 4em + width of background */
  width:100%;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>

<div class="alt">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your new code:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.use-px {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.use-percentage {
  width: 100px;
  height: 300px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.left-over-image {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.left-over-image::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  max-width:50px;
  background-image: url(https://www.w3schools.com/images/w3schools_green.jpg);
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  transform:translateX(-100%);
  transition: all 1s;
}
.left-over-image:hover::before {
  transform:translateX(0);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="use-px">
    <!-- It will use 50px, because 25% of 300px is 75px. -->
    <div class="left-over-image"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="use-percentage">
    <!-- It will use 100%, because 25% of 100px is 25px. -->
    <div class="left-over-image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, but the `.box` is also added to the second div and it uses min()

Comment: @PierBJX I simply wrote an optimized code, the min in the second box is doing nothing since I made the background size to be 0

Comment: Then, I don't understand how this will set 100% or 4em for the background-position-x ?

Comment: @PierBJX did you run the code and test it? the pseudo element is doing the job using the combination of with/max-width

Comment: @PierBJX I have split both code and removed box from the second one so you can better see

Comment: It means that I have to know the size of the background-size. Indeed, my css is more tricky. I will update the post if you don't mind.